# sql query to sort timestamp

Tags: sql

```
select  b.id as st,a.appname as name_st ,
b.no_clicks as clicks, 
b.first_usage as ft , 
b.last_usage as lu from 
(select appname, appid from oneclick_apps) a ,
(SELECT   application_id AS id, COUNT(*) AS NO_CLICKS,
TO_CHAR( min(accessed_time),'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') 
FIRST_USAGE,
TO_CHAR( max(accessed_time),'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') 
LAST_USAGE 
FROM  user_db 
WHERE  upper(user_id) like upper('e243378')  
GROUP BY user_application ) b 
where b.id = a.appid  order by lu asc
```

is my query....which sorts in ascending order...only in terms of year...what modifications should i make so that it sorts for entire dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: Please, if you expect others to take the time to answer your question, you should at least take the time to make your question readable. StackOverflow supports proper code formatting. Just select your code, and click the `{}` button. It's not difficult, and not doing it really sends the message that "I don't want to spend even one second to make things easier for you. Instead, I expect you to use *extra* time to decode my question."

Comment: it's the tick box and not the up arrow. that threw me at first.

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech: Well, actually it's nice to use both. :) But you are right, it's the tick that is used to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.id as st, a.appname as name_st, 
       b.no_clicks as clicks, b.first_usage as ft , b.last_usage as lu 
from (select appname, appid from oneclick_apps) a, 
     (SELECT application_id AS id, COUNT(*) AS NO_CLICKS, 
             TO_CHAR( min(accessed_time),'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') FIRST_USAGE, 
             TO_CHAR( max(accessed_time),'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') LAST_USAGE 
      FROM user_db 
      WHERE upper(user_id) like upper('e243378')
      GROUP BY user_application ) b 
where b.id = a.appid 
order by lu asc
```

I see three options off the top of my head.

1. Don't convert your timestamps to
   strings.
2. Convert your timestamps to strings
   that sort correctly as strings. (YYYY-MM-DD
   hh:mm:ss)
3. Include both converted and
   unconverted timestamps. Display the converted; sort on the unconverted. (A variation
   on #1)

I prefer #1. If client applications need a different display, let them handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would hate to have to maintain your code. No formatting causes BIG headaches.

OK, so lets see if we can help.

Why not rather move the formatting to the outside scope.

Something like

```
select  b.id as st,
        a.appname as name_st ,
        b.no_clicks as clicks, 
        TO_CHAR( b.first_usage,'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') as ft , 
        TO_CHAR( b.last_usage,'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') as lu 
from    (
            select  appname, 
                    appid   
            from    oneclick_apps
        ) a ,
        (
            SELECT  application_id AS id, 
                    COUNT(*) AS NO_CLICKS,
                    min(accessed_time) FIRST_USAGE,
                    max(accessed_time) LAST_USAGE 
            FROM    user_db 
            WHERE  upper(user_id) like upper('e243378')  
            GROUP BY user_application 
        ) b 
where b.id = a.appid  
order by b.last_usage asc
```